# Python: sorting sublist values in nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a nested list:
`list = [[3,2,1],[8,7,9],[5,6,4]]`

I want to sort each sublist in ascending order. My though was to loop through the list, but it only wants to sort the last sublist.

`for i in list:
    newList = sorted[i]`

So for this example the for loop would loop through the whole list, but only sort the last sublist [5,6,4]. How do I make it sort all the sublists?

Python version: 2.7.10

OS: OS X El Capitan

Comment: Replace the body of the loop with `i.sort()`.  That sorts the (sub)list in-place.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the value of newList on each iteration in the for loop. Hence, after the for loop ends, the value of newList is equal to the sorted value of the last list in the original nested list. Do this:

```
>>> list = [[3,2,1],[8,7,9],[5,6,4]]
>>> newlist = map(sorted, list)
>>> newlist
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new list and assigning it to a new name, then throwing it away. Use the `sort` method to sort each list reference to in-place. Also note that it doesn't make sense to use a list reference to index the main list, and that you should avoid naming variables with the same name as built-in functions (`list` in this case).

```
>>> l = [[3,2,1],[8,7,9],[5,6,4]]
>>> for i in l:
...     i.sort()
...
>>> l
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because you are creating a new sorted list (`sorted()` creates a new list) and assigning it to a variable (`newList`). This variable goes unused.

Python lists have a `.sort()` method. So your loop code can work as follows

```
for sublist in list:
    sublist.sort() #sorts the sublist in place
print list #all sublists will be sorted in ascending order
```

As mentioned by Nehal J Wani, you can also use a map to apply one function to each element of a list.

```
newSortedList = map(sorted,list) #newSortedList will have all sublists sorted
```